# VueJS sum pivot table

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am learning VueJS and am in the process of porting a very simple app I wrote in Laravel with blade as the template engine.

I am keeping the existing back end which consists of a simple restful api of 3 tables: Books, Places and a pivot Books_Places.

The json looks something like this:

```
books:
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "foo bar",
  "places": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "library 1",
      "pivot": {
        "book_id": "1",
        "place_id": "1",
        "quantity": "50",
        "id": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "library 2",
      "pivot": {
        "book_id": "1",
        "place_id": "2",
        "quantity": "75",
        "id": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In blade I had the following line built into a "for book in books" cycle which I loved because of its simplicity:

```
{{ $book->places->sum('pivot.quantity') }}
```

I am trying to accomplish the same in VueJS but not sure what the simplest approach is, I'd appreciate your opinions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a method to sum up the quantities using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
methods: {
    sumOfQuantities: function(book) {
       return book.places.reduce(function(sum, next) {
           return sum + Number(next.pivot.quantity);
       }, 0);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Since your `quantity` is a string, you need to convert it to a Number (e.g. using `Number()`).

You can then access it in your template using `v-text` for example:

```
<div v-for="book in books">
    <div v-text="sumOfQuantities(book)"></div>
</div>
```